# Firebase Uncaught Reference Error Backbone / Fetch called on a Firebase collection, ignoring.

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, firebase

I am trying to link up backbone with firebase

In the forge I have the following structure laid out:

```
-myfirebasename
     -user
         -first_name
         -last_name
```

This code:

```
  var Items = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
    url: user,
    firebase: "https://myfirebasename.firebaseio.com"
  });
```

gives me an uncaught reference error, user is not defined. Obviously this is wrong (being a url param), but I gave it a shot because the other two below didn't worek..

If I replace url with `/user` I get `Fetch called on a Firebase collection, ignoring.`

If I use model: user instead, I get `fetch called on ...ignoring` and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'idAttribute' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Melbourne2991, you indeed need to use the model property as you tried before:

```
var Items = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
    model: User,
    firebase: "https://myfirebasename.firebaseio.com"
  });
```

The key point is obviously to define User before you call this, for instance:

```
var User = Backbone.Firebase.Model.extend({
  defaults: function() { //maybe but some default values... }, 
  initialize: function() { //or some initializing code... }, 
});
```

The Backbone.Firebase.* and Backbone.* are very similar in behavior (thanksfully!), a collection needs to know what it is a collection of, and the way to tell it that is first to define the Model type (extend a Backbone.*.Model) and then pass it in the model key. The firebase thing is just to give a smart url to backbone to do the fetching and give it some special rules for fetching, updating, etc.